# firebreath mac osx, bundle - link binary with libraries disable

Tags: macos, bundle, static-libraries, firebreath

I working with Firebreath 1.7, MacOSX 10.8.3, Xcode 4.6.3.
I want add boost::chrono as static library to my plugin.
After running prepmac.sh i have my_plugin bundle target. I choose my_plugin target in project/targets tab and don't see option "Link binary With Libraries".

How i can add boost::chrono library to my_plugin by another method?

Comment: I found decision! Question can be closed.

Comment: Linking/Other Linker Flags - need to change values there

Answer (score 0):

Changing things manually there is not the correct way to do it; you should never change the project files without changing the cmake files, because eventually you'll need to rerun the prep script.

First of all, are you using system boost?  boost::chrono is not part of the boost that firebreath includes, which is a subset of the boost features to keep size down for those who don't want to deal with it.  If you are using part firebreath boost and part your own, you could have problems.

If you've configured system boost correctly, you should be able to just add this to the end of your PluginConfig.cmake file and rerun the prep script:

```
add_boost_library(chrono)
```

Barring that, you could also just do it using cmake directly, which would mean adding a [target_link_libraries](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) command to your CMakeLists.txt or Mac/projectDef.cmake file at the end, something like:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} boost_chrono)
```

(you'd need to find out for sure what the library name is; you might even need to use [find_library](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3afind_library) to locate it).